# Asking for sponsorship for an event from an employer

Tags: off-site-events

I think this query comes under this community but let me know if it is better suited elsewhere.

How should I go about asking my employer for sponsorship for an event being run by a small amateur organisation that I am a member of?

I work full time for a small, well funded, tech startup. We have less than 50 employees. We are less than a year old and everyone knows everyone in both of our offices. I feel I have a good rapport with my superiors and all colleagues in general.

The value of the sponsorship is very small, anything from €25 - €100. The event that they are sponsoring is run over one day and is family friendly. The event has absolutely no relevance to what the company do. The company will gain very little from the sponsorship, in fact probably nothing other than supporting a club that I am member of.

How should I ask for such sponsorship, who should I be asking and via what method? Or, should I be asking in the first place? I am not worried about being rejected just about possibly going about it the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an HR department, ask them :)  If not, ask your boss!

Comment: Hr will at least know who you should be asking, so they're a good place to start.

Comment: As @JaneS says, if you don't know whom to ask or where to begin, start either with your boss or HR. If your firm is small and you are on a first-name basis with the CEO, ask the CEO. I worked once for a company whose CEO was a skinflint. And a jerk who could rip your head from your shoulders depending on what he had eaten that morning. But the Vice-P was a good guy. I made it a habit of laying out my requests to the Vice-P, who knew how to ask the Big Boss and get a "yes" answer.

Comment: _"The event has absolutely no relevance to what the company do. The company will gain very little from the sponsorship, in fact probably nothing other than supporting a club that I am member of."_

This part might be problem for the company and make them stand still. They are willingly looking for some with a common point or similar interest area or at least similar industry.

Comment: For that small amount of money wouldn't it be easier, faster, and cheaper for all parties involved if you simply sponsor it out of your own pocket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I ask for such sponsorship, who should I be asking and via
>   what method? Or, should I be asking in the first place?

If you have an HR rep, you should ask her/him first. Often, they know if a program is in place for sponsorships like this, and if not, they know who to ask.

If you don't have an HR group, ask your boss who to talk with.

At least in my part of the US, in startups where I have worked, the companies often have a budget for community support monies. This sponsorship could easily come from that.